# How many cells can "go to special" select?

Tags: microsoft-excel

Unfortunately, I've been tasked with mining through some data copy log files to sort out ones that have "access is denied" flags on them. I cannot post the file due to sensitive information, but here is a screenshot of a small section that demonstrates what I am attempting to do:

[image]

The log imports into Excel in this way. All files that encounter an Access is Denied error occupy Column A, while data about successful file copies occupy columns B and C.

This log file is over 300,000 lines long, but there are only around 8700 errors. By selecting column A, and pressing F5, I can get "Go To Special". From there, I can select Blanks, which will filter out all rows with Column A being blank. At this point, I can delete the rows which have a blank cell in column A. However, I can only seem to do this about 20,000 rows at a time. My question is, **how many cells can "Go to Special" actually select?** Does it depend on the version of Excel?

Comment: You can set an autofilter and select cells with "access is denied" on them, then

Comment: @fernando.reyes It's not that simple, one line has the directory/path of the denied file, then two lines below is the string "Access is Denied". I'm trying to clear out all rows that have a blank cell in column A.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your file to have an outlook of what must be done?

Comment: @fernando.reyes I would love to, but it's got some sensitive data in it that probably shouldn't be posted publicly, I'm sorry.

Comment: At this point it's a theoretical discussion with no data to present. Seems there is nothing to talk about then.

Comment: @ejbytes It's really not... it's a question of data limits with Excel, nothing more. What my data is shouldn't matter, and my inability to provide sensitive data to you shouldn't change the nature of the question.

Comment: You mention copy, data, log files, access denied, flags. What is the nature of copy? Are you importing? If you are importing, how? If you are importing, are you using delimiters? What's special about column A? If it's a log file, then explain from again from the top of this paragraph. You need to explain exactly how you are dealing with "data". That could be a factor. I don't know why you'd want to find blanks either in a log file. If you can't lay it out in this nature, I don't think you'll find what you want in this forum for the nature of the question and how it's posed.

Comment: @ejbytes I apologize for the confusion, and have reworked the question. Please let me know what other information you need.

Comment: Looks like a maximum of 5 columns? Have you tried selecting A,B,C,D,E, then F5, blanks?

Comment: @ejbytes I'm attempting to use Go to Special on only column A in order to find all rows that have a blank in column A.

Comment: You can select blanks with an autofilter, and it will work for all the length of your list

Comment: Yes Fernando is right. This is much better. Select "blanks", or select all except "", in filters.

Comment: That's a lot easier than using a Go to Special and deleting rows. Whoever wants to post an answer can do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you need is select blanks, you can do it with an autofilter.

Select all the length of your list and [image: filter], then on the filter dropbox you can select "Blanks" and all the blank cells in your list will be selected.

Then you can delete them all and concentrate on the actual data that matter to you.